# How can front-end application based on AngularJs consume backend application based on Spring MVC whic is on Tomacat 7 server

Tags: angularjs, spring-mvc, tomcat7

I am trying to develop web app using AngularJS as front-end which is separate application from backend  Spring MVC on Tomcat 7.How can my front-end consume backend ?

Comment: What do you mean by 'consume'. The word indicates that you'll want to learn about webservices...

Comment: For example,I start to create AngularJS app using Grunt server and Spring MVC like REST on Tomcat Server.After finished that to separate app I would like to use front-end app on Tomcat Server to ,,consume,, resource URL of my back-end.

Comment: What problem are you having exactly? Are you having issues at front end or back end?

Comment: Can front and back be on different server and communicate throw URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) or [$resource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource) for consuming your RESTful Webservices.

HTTP Simple GET request example:

```
$http({
  method: 'GET',
  url: '/someUrl'
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
    // this callback will be called asynchronously
    // when the response is available
  }, function errorCallback(response) {
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.
  })
```

Resource example:

```
var User = $resource('/user/:userId', {userId:'@id'});
var user = User.get({userId:123}, function() {
  user.abc = true;
  user.$save();
})
```

Comment: There is no problem that my front-end is on one server and back-end on another.

Comment: No. Just use the proper url: `http(s)://yourHost/yourApi..`. And please accept this answer if it helped you.